# 6g treating complete flag as output flag resulting in "pack: cannot open" error

Tags: go

Started getting a `pack: cannot open` error on all my go projects.

Tried to run a simple go file:

main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

and got the same result:

```
$ go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
pack: cannot open $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_go_.6
```

I did have a new file in the directory called `mplete` which seemed to be the output from the 6g compiler.

running the steps output from `go run -x main.go` manually I found the 6g compiler is taking the flag `-complete` and reading it as `-o mplete`. Which sets the output file to `meplete`

```
$ ls
main.go  work_tmp
$ /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g -o $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_go_.6 -p command-line-arguments -complete -D _/tmp/taco -I $WORK ./main.go
$ ls
main.go  mplete  work_tmp
```

Changing the `-complete` flag changed the file that was output:

```
$ ls
main.go  work_tmp
$ /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g -o $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_go_.6 -p command-line-arguments -cotaco -D _/tmp/taco -I $WORK ./main.go
$ ls
main.go  taco  work_tmp
```

My `go evn`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/jpoz/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

I had two version of go installed on my machine:

go1.0.3 in `/usr/local/go`
and
go1.1.1 in `/usr/local/bin/go`

`which go` would use go1.1.1 but since GOROOT was set to `/usr/local/go` the build was using the **old** 6g compiler!!